# is there any way to delete an object while creating it?

Tags: java, oop

I'm practising towards finals and I have faced this question -

Given the following code, is there any way that the there is an implementation of class A such that at the end it will print 5 in one run of the program, then in other run of the program 4, then another run 3...till 0.

Can assume that it's deterministic so functions will generate always the same results.

Can't delete any code in class A and not in the main, and able only to edit A class.

```
public class A {

    int i, j;

    public A(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<A> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        s.add(new A(3,1));
        s.add(new A(1,3));
        s.add(new A(3,1));
        s.add(new A(3,1));
        s.add(new A(2,1));

        System.out.println(s.size());

    }

}
```

I was thinking to add kind of static HASHMAP and every time I create an object I will add it to there and I will check if one key already exists then I would like to "not create" the object if one with same values already exists... but not able to implement it.

Comment: I think you're looking to implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your `A` class.

Comment: What do you mean by "print 5/4/3/2/1/0"? It'll only print a single number, and it already prints 5.

Comment: I will edit to be more clear, 
is there one implementation that it will print 5, another implementation it will print 4...etc

Comment: Yes, @LuiggiMendoza is right about generating the hash collisions, and that will allow results 5 down to 1, but how to stop even 1 entry being inserted, so get the answer 0?

Comment: Is there a good way to implement 4 given that `new A(3,1)` occurs three times?

Comment: @GemTaylor well, adding even `null` to a `Set` will give you a size of 1, so having 0 as answer after using `add` is impossible.

Comment: To get 4 I guess you would have to implement another static member  - maybe a multiset that auto-records the created instances in the constructor and uses the number of repeated entries in that multiset to decide that one of them is not unique. Not pretty. The trivial fix would simply be a static counter that determines that the first N created entries are unique and the rest always collide, just by using the counted index as the hash. Still not fixed the zero case.

Comment: @GemTaylor one thing is obvious when you do new(3,1) you get into the constructor and from there i need to manage it. so first as i said i tried with hash map to check if a key value already entered in the constructor of A, what now? how can i "cancel" the creation or refer to same object so set won't count it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza can you be more specific how to implement this correctly? I'm just having trouble to manage it from the constructor as it must create something...

Comment: First thing first. Please update your question to explain how you want/need the output becomes 5/4/3/2/1/0. If you have to run the same code but expect different results, I think it'd be very hard to accomplish.

Comment: What we are saying is you do create it, but overload the hashCode method so it claims to have the same hash as the other entry. That probably need you to calculate and store the hashcode as a non-static value member during construction, which is why I suggest the simpler trick with a single static counter that you copy to this hashcode value member.

Comment: I have edited and being more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to implement [equals and hashcode](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/) into class A. You should implement them in such a way that it will cause collisions when adding items into Set `s`.

By default, it should print out the number 5.

But, if we make the following edit:

```java
public class A {

    int i, j;

    public A(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // First we check if the object is null
        // Then we check if it's the same class as this one
        if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!= this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        A objectA = (A) obj;

        if(this.i == objectA.i) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() 
    { 

        return this.i; 
    }
```

This particular implementation will result in printing out '3'. This is because we set it so that the hashcode is equal to `i`. Therefore when we add two instances of class `A` to the set, they will collide.

In our case, when instances of class `A` are added, the values for i are `3, 1, 3, 3, 2`, there are 3 unique values of `i` (3, 1, 2), so therefore it will print `3`.

From here you can come up with different implementations to get different values.

Comment: Thanks! so basically every Set\Hash uses an equal method and hash so if i override the hash and always return same value lets say 1. it will always have collisions and it will then make comparisons using equal method, am i right?

Comment: Sounds like you got the right idea. You'll have to manipulate the hash and equals override functions in order to cause a certain number of collisions. I.e. if you set the `equals` function to return 0, then the final size of set `s` will be 1, because all the items added will be considered equal.

Comment: @omrib40 Let me know if you need me to clarify anything in my answer. If it looks good to you, feel free to hit the accept answer button!